# Slide in/out on component mount/unmonunt

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MaterialUI for React. It has some transition components like Fade, Slide etc.

Is there a way to trigger those transitions when a component gets mounted or unmounted?

Comment: With a specific code example it would be easier to test a working solution. But in theory you can add a css class when the component mounts that triggers a css animation. When the component unmounts would be a bit more complex, as you would need to add a css class and debounce the unmount until the animation finishes.